# meta viewport property not making a webpage fit the device's width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm taking a Udacity course on making a site responsive and I tried applying `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` on a non-responsive site. The result was that page did not try to fit the device's width. Am I misunderstanding something?

[image]

Comment: Change the ratio in your Dev tools(2 => 1)

Comment: Check if the larger elements (or the elements that aren't responsive) have **fixed width**.

Comment: @Vucko doing so. BTW is my question badly formed. I'm not sure why I got the down vote...

Answer (score 2):

Your html page probably has a wrapping container that has a fixed width in pixel. `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` will not make your webpage responsive, but rather has an effect on the ratio sizes that i.e. fonts will be rendered with.

Try giving the container a width of `100%` and go from there.

Comment: I thought the same, maybe we can be sure if we get some source code

Answer (score 0):

It appears part of your page consists of a table. Most likely that table simply won't fit inside the available width, forcing the page to overflow the device, so to speak.

It could also be any other element either having a fixed width that's too high or that for other reasons can't scale to fit the available width, like text with `white-space: nowrap`. Without seeing more of your code it's impossible to tell.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

you should try this.

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel what??

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg I was very hasty reading your comment. Sorry. I thought you meant "would changing it 1 solve the problem?"

Comment: @AlexanderSuraphel I see, no problem. Sorry about the tone of my response :)

Answer (score -1):

Change the ratio in your Dev tools. Now, it is 2. Change it to 1.

Comment: This wouldn't help the underlying problem OP is trying to solve, only change how the page appears in the emulator.